# What does the R8 maximumremovedandroidloglevel option?

Tags: android, android-r8

I am currently removing Android Logging by using the common Proguard/R8 configuration:

```
-assumenosideeffects class android.util.Log {
    public static boolean isLoggable(java.lang.String, int);
    public static int v(...);
    public static int i(...);
    public static int w(...);
    public static int d(...);
    public static int e(...);
}
```

But I have found this [official documentation](https://source.android.com/docs/core/tests/debug/understanding-logging#log-standards) which recommends to set the following R8 option with the corresponding log level (in the example 4) too:

```
-maximumremovedandroidloglevel 4
```

I checked to R8 source code to understand what this additional option does. I only found [this comment](https://r8.googlesource.com/r8/+/refs/heads/main/src/main/java/com/android/tools/r8/ir/optimize/library/LogMethodOptimizer.java#113):

> Replace Android logging statements like Log.w(...) and Log.IsLoggable(..., WARNING) at or below a certain logging level by false.

**Is this really required and what are the benefit vs only using the
`assumenosideeffects` rule?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was curious about this rule as well, so I have researched a bit.

**Is this really required and what are the benefit vs only using the assumenosideeffects rule?**
This `-maximumremovedandroidloglevel` rule is intended to have the same effect as the `-assumenosideeffects` for `Log.*` methods, therefore it might be used as a *complete substitute*.
However, as of the latest version (3.3.75), it performs slightly differently than `-assumenosideeffects`. If you intend to remove all `Log.*` method invocations - then you shouldn't care (you can use one, or the other). But if you're removing only a portion of those methods and you rely on `Log#isLoggable`, then I'd suggest sticking to your current configuration, and avoiding adding the `-maximumremovedandroidloglevel` rule to your proguard configuration file.

---

**A deeper dig**

Let's assume we have the following lines of code in our source code, and then I'll show what it looks like after R8 processing with different configurations.

```
if (Log.isLoggable("FOO_TAG", Log.VERBOSE)) {
    Log.v("FOO_TAG", "verbose message");
}

if (Log.isLoggable("FOO_TAG", Log.WARN)) {
    Log.w("FOO_TAG", "warn message");
}
```

**<1>** R8 v3.3.75, with the following rules (note that I have commented out the `w` and `e` methods):

```
-assumenosideeffects class android.util.Log {
    public static boolean isLoggable(java.lang.String, int);
    public static int v(...);
    public static int i(...);
#    public static int w(...);
    public static int d(...);
#    public static int e(...);
}
```

Produces the following output:

```
if (Log.isLoggable("FOO_TAG", 5)) {
    Log.w("FOO_TAG", "warn message");
}
```

R8 removed the VERBOSE logs as expected. Note that it keeps the `Log#isLoggable` method invocation where the level (the second parameter) is `WARN` (5).

**<2>** R8 v3.3.75, with the following rules (4 means we want to remove all the log methods up to `INFO`, including):

```
-maximumremovedandroidloglevel 4
```

Produces the following output:

```
Log.w("FOO_TAG", "warn message");
```

Note that this rule keeps the `Log#w` method invocation, but removes the `Log#isLoggable` invocation (this is where the behavior slightly differs).
This means that the latest R8 version in regards to `-maximumremovedandroidloglevel` doesn't work exactly as advertised ([here](https://r8.googlesource.com/r8/+/b1389a6695e455d9496a8b54e10db396adff356d)):

> Example: The value of android.util.log.INFO is 4. Therefore,
> specifying `-maximumremovedandroidloglevel 4` will remove all calls to
> Log.v(), Log.d(), and Log.i(), as well as it will replace calls to
> Log.isLoggable(X, {2, 3, 4}) by false.

**<3>** R8 from [the tip](https://r8.googlesource.com/r8/+/8f081fd6fd8ad9214304a39f656cc88e4ba3f113) of the `main` branch, with the following rules (4 means we want to remove all the log methods up to `INFO`, including):

```
-maximumremovedandroidloglevel 4
```

Produces the following output:

```
if (Log.isLoggable("FOO_TAG", 5)) {
    Log.w("FOO_TAG", "warn message");
}
```

It seems that `main` branch includes a fix that reinstates the behavior parity of two approaches (`Log#isLoggable` with `WARN` as a parameter was not removed).
The relevant diff between the `main` and `3.3.75` tag is those two commits: [1](https://r8.googlesource.com/r8/+/e6756f427662a2e68d82ba100c8f87984cd8468e), [2](https://r8.googlesource.com/r8/+/4c8ca96f117b2c963695814984ab7042375cdc85).

---

**Why the [official documentation](https://source.android.com/docs/core/tests/debug/understanding-logging#log-standards) includes both `-assumenosideeffects` and `-maximumremovedandroidloglevel`?**
According to my tests - it seems misleading, as they should have suggested to using one or the other, definitely not both.
I have opened [an issue](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/252443283) with a request to elaborate on that.