Upgrading to cronet-embedded:119.6045.31 causes R8 error on maximumremovedandroidloglevel rule
After upgrading to cronet-embedded:119.6045.31, and I'm getting this build failure from R8:
  ERROR: /re/dac/ted/gradle_home/caches/transforms-3/30da92821347fd2259fb4e0490f978c1/transformed/jetified-cronet-embedded-119.6045.31/proguard.txt:103:34: R8: Expected char '-' at /re/dac/ted/gradle_home/caches/transforms-3/30da92821347fd2259fb4e0490f978c1/transformed/jetified-cronet-embedded-119.6045.31/proguard.txt:103:34
   -maximumremovedandroidloglevel 1 class ** {
                                    ^
   Execution failed for task ':app:minifyReleaseWithR8'. org.gradle.workers.internal.DefaultWorkerExecutor$WorkExecutionException: A failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.R8Task$R8Runnable

The only documentation on on maximumremovedandroidloglevel I can find doesn't show a class argument for the rule:

Logging can be removed on a per-APK basis via ProGuard rulesets by R8
at compile time. The following example removes everything below INFO
level logging for android.util.Log:
# This allows proguard to strip isLoggable() blocks containing only <=INFO log
# code from release builds.
-assumenosideeffects class android.util.Log {
  static *** i(...);
  static *** d(...);
  static *** v(...);
  static *** isLoggable(...);
}
-maximumremovedandroidloglevel 4


Is class allowed? I don't think the cronet folks would ship an obviously-broken library like this.

This question is related: https://stackoverflow.com/q/73876633/9636

TLDR: cronet-embedded:119.6045.31 seems to require AGP 8.3+
I reported this issue as https://issues.chromium.org/issues/332584397
R8 has directives that allow rules only to apply to certain versions, so you can make this proguard file work with both AGP <8.3 an AGP 8.3+
Sadly, I can’t find any more comprehensive documentation for how do use the maximumremovedandroidloglevel directive, nor can I find any cronet or R8 release notes.
I think the problem is that we’re still on AGP 8.1.3. I found what I think are the R8 sources for AGP 8.1.2, and it looks like the parser expects the start of a new option line after parsing maximumremovedandroidloglevel 1, which explains the error message:
        skipWhitespace();
        Integer maxRemovedAndroidLogLevel = acceptInteger();
        if (maxRemovedAndroidLogLevel != null && maxRemovedAndroidLogLevel >= 1) {
          configurationBuilder.joinMaxRemovedAndroidLogLevel(maxRemovedAndroidLogLevel);
        } else {
          throw parseError("Expected integer greater than or equal to 1", getPosition());
        }
      }```
next iteration:
```expectChar('-');
...
    private void expectChar(char c) throws ProguardRuleParserException {
      if (!acceptChar(c)) {
        throw parseError("Expected char '" + c + "'");
      }
    }```

But in [R8 8.3's Parser](https://r8.googlesource.com/r8/+/refs/heads/8.3/src/main/java/com/android/tools/r8/shaking/ProguardConfigurationParser.java#484) they now consume the `class` parameter
```      if (parseMaximumRemovedAndroidLogLevelRule(optionStart)) {
        return true;
      }
...
    private boolean parseMaximumRemovedAndroidLogLevelRule(Position start)
        throws ProguardRuleParserException {
      if (acceptString("maximumremovedandroidloglevel")) {
        skipWhitespace();
        // First parse the mandatory log level int.
        Integer maxRemovedAndroidLogLevel = acceptInteger();
        if (maxRemovedAndroidLogLevel == null
            || maxRemovedAndroidLogLevel < MaximumRemovedAndroidLogLevelRule.NONE) {
          throw parseError("Expected integer greater than or equal to 1", getPosition());
        }
        MaximumRemovedAndroidLogLevelRule.Builder builder =
            MaximumRemovedAndroidLogLevelRule.builder()
                .setMaxRemovedAndroidLogLevel(maxRemovedAndroidLogLevel)
                .setOrigin(origin)
                .setStart(start);
        // Check if we can parse any class annotations or flag.
        if (parseClassAnnotationsAndFlags(builder)) {
          // Parse the remainder of the class specification.
          parseClassSpecFromClassTypeInclusive(builder, false);
        } else {
          // Otherwise check if we can parse a class name.
          parseClassType(
              builder,
              // Parse the remainder of the class specification.
              () -> parseClassSpecFromClassNameInclusive(builder, false),
              // In case of an error, move position back to the place we expected an (optional)
              // class type.
              expectedClassTypeStart -> position = expectedClassTypeStart.getOffsetAsInt());
        }
        if (builder.hasClassType()) {
          Position end = getPosition();
          configurationBuilder.addRule(
              builder.setEnd(end).setSource(getSourceSnippet(contents, start, end)).build());
        } else {
          configurationBuilder.joinMaxRemovedAndroidLogLevel(maxRemovedAndroidLogLevel);
        }
        return true;
      }
      return false;
    }```


I see you figured this out yourself already \o/.The parsing of -maximumremovedandroidloglevel to also allow a class specification was added in https://r8-review.git.corp.google.com/c/r8/+/78044, and should also be in R8 8.2, so AGP 8.2.2 might also work. The reason for the missing documentation of -maximumremovedandroidloglevel is that it is not officially supported by R8.
